# Different behavior when I refresh the page

Tags: jquery, browser-cache, page-refresh

I'm creating a jQuery webpage, and I have an instruction which sets automatically the width of the header tag. But when I run it the 1st time jQuery DOES ignore it and sets it to 1542px.

The weird thing is that when I refresh the page, or when I re-run it from the Netbeans into a new tab, it DOESN'T ignore that instruction and works as I wanted, everything well and perfect.

Even more weird: all of this happens only in Firefox, but works all right with IE (didn't tried other browsers).

**CODE**

I have this piece of code from my html:

```
<script>
    var data = "";

    var success = function (data) {

        OneMenu.createMenu("#mainMenu", data);
    };

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/MenuOne/example_menu.json",
        data: data,
        success: success
    });
</script>
```

Inside *createMenu* I'm defining all my code using JSON, also my jQuery instructions are in there, and I don't know if you will need more code or a jsfiddle or anythig -just tell me if you need it.

If you have understood what is happening, my guess is that the problem comes from the cache memory, but I do really have no idea how to fix this...

Thanks mates

Comment: You seem to be asking about the function that sets the header width, but I don't see that function here. Is the ajax even relevant?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know where my problem comes from. The thing is that the 1st time i run my program, it is a mess, but when I refresh the page it works good.
I am not asking for the solution itself. I just need someone that explains to me what is happening and give me some advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found what is happening: http://ask.metafilter.com/200230/My-webpage-wont-update-unless-I-hit-the-refresh-button

I don't know how to solve the problem yet, but aknowledging where it comes from is a start. Hope this can help somebody. (I'll leave the post open for if anyone has suggestions).